# python_select with fink-installed python?

Tags: python, fink

How do I use python_select with fink installed python?  It won't find it and I don't want to go through the whole process of installing python using macports.  I got python_select from macports though.  It reports:

```
Available versions:
current none python26-apple
```

I used fink to install python in:

```
/sw/bin/python2.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following in my machine:

```
Available versions:
current none python26 python26-apple
```

I guess it is looking up the python versions that are available in path. Since, MacPorts go to /opt; Fink goes to /sw. **Is fink on your path?** What is contained in $PATH.

> I would suggest that you use macports. python_select works well with macports installation.

See the following discussion and the suggestion is to use macports:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/12952/macports-vs-fink.

I personally use macports.

```
sudo port install python27 
sudo port install python_select
sudo python_select python27
```

Comment: I think I will switch to macports.  Do you use python26 or python27?

Comment: @Neil G: I use python26 for certain purpose and will switch to python27 soon.